# Vulkan/OpenGL interop compute shader image tiling issue

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I am using Vulkan with GLSL compute shaders to do post processing on a texture rendered in OpenGL. It works fine for the most part, but when the vertical resolution of the texture is within certain ranges, I see very weird anomalies where gl_GlobalInvocationID seems to be messed up.

An example compute shader that demonstrates this looks like

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

#define WORKGROUP_SIZE 32

layout(local_size_x=WORKGROUP_SIZE, local_size_y=WORKGROUP_SIZE, local_size_z=1) in;

layout(binding=0, rgba8) uniform image2D input_tex;
layout(binding=1, rgba8) uniform image2D output_tex;

void main()
{
    vec4 red = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 black = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    if(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x == 0 || gl_GlobalInvocationID.y == 0)
    {
        imageStore(output_tex, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), red);
    }
    else
    {
        imageStore(output_tex, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), black);
    }
}
```

Depending on the vertical resolution, I get odd results: 482+, 241-256, 121-128, 55-64 work fine, but 257-481, 129-240, 65-121, <55 are incorrect. See below.

Vertical resolution 482 working:
[image: 960x482 Working]

Vertical resolution 480 broken:
[image: 960x480 Not Working]

I create the textures via:

```
vk::ImageCreateInfo image_create_info(
    vk::ImageCreateFlags(),
    vk::ImageType::e2D,
    vk::Format::eR8G8B8A8Unorm,
    {width, height, 1},
    1, 
    1,
    vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1,
    vk::ImageTiling::eOptimal,
    vk::ImageUsageFlagBits::eColorAttachment |
        vk::ImageUsageFlagBits::eSampled |
        vk::ImageUsageFlagBits::eTransferSrc |
        vk::ImageUsageFlagBits::eStorage
);

image = device.createImage(image_create_info);

vk::MemoryRequirements memory_requirements = device.getImageMemoryRequirements(image);
memory_size = memory_requirements.size;

vk::ExportMemoryAllocateInfo export_allocate_info(
    vk::ExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits::eOpaqueFd);
vk::MemoryAllocateInfo memory_allocate_info(
    memory_size,
    memory_type // Standard way of finding this using eDeviceLocal
);
memory_allocate_info.pNext = &export_allocate_info;
device_memory = device.allocateMemory(memory_allocate_info);
device.bindImageMemory(image, device_memory, 0);

vk::MemoryGetFdInfoKHR memory_info(device_memory, vk::ExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits::eOpaqueFd);
opaque_handle = device.getMemoryFdKHR(memory_info, dynamic_loader);

// Create OpenGL texture
glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &opengl_tex);
glCreateMemoryObjectsEXT(1, &opengl_memory);
glImportMemoryFdEXT(opengl_memory, memory_size, GL_HANDLE_TYPE_OPAQUE_FD_EXT, opaque_handle);
glTextureStorageMem2DEXT(opengl_tex, 1, GL_RGBA8, width, height, opengl_memory, 0);
```

I render to a texture in OpenGL, then use `glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST)` to copy the rendered image to `opengl_tex` from above and then execute the command buffer containing the above shader. After that, I blit the texture back and render it to the screen in OpenGL. (Using semaphores for synchronization).

The creation of the command buffer looks like

```
vk::CommandBufferBeginInfo begin_info(
    vk::CommandBufferUsageFlagBits());
command_buffer.begin(begin_info);
command_buffer.bindPipeline(vk::PipelineBindPoint::eCompute, pipeline);
command_buffer.bindDescriptorSets(vk::PipelineBindPoint::eCompute, pipeline_layout, 0, 1, &descriptor_set, 0, nullptr);
command_buffer.dispatch((uint32_t)ceil(width/float(WORKGROUP_SIZE), (uint32_t)ceil(height/float(WORKGROUP_SIZE)), 1);
command_buffer.end();
```

I checked several times that I wasn't hard coding a size somewhere (besides workgroup size).

I also made a utility to read in a png image and execute the same shader and write out the output (bypassing the OpenGL interop) and that works regardless of dimension.

I have a requirement to be able to process a 480x480 image, so any help would be much appreciated. If there's any other info you need, I can provide more code.

(FYI I am using a GTX 1080 with NVidia driver 410.78 on Linux and Vulkan 1.1.85.0)

EDIT:
Using the following shader snippet:

```
vec4 color = vec4(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x/480.0, gl_GlobalInvocationID.y/480.0, 0.0, 1.0);
imageStore(output_tex, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), color);
```

I get the results

480x482 image working:

[image: 480x482 Working]

480x480 image broken:

[image: 480x480 Broken]

Comment: Given you say the Vulkan part of this works without the OpenGL interop, it sounds like your question is mistitled. Given the compute shader works without the interop, why do you think it's the global invocation IDs which are messed up? It sounds like they work fine.

Comment: If you use linear tiling rather than optimal tiling, does it improve?

Comment: Sorry if the title is misleading - I agree that the IDs are working as they should, but since it is appearing as though they are somewhere else, it is a symptom of the problem.

Comment: I tried changing the tiling to linear, but I get a validation error that the combination is invalid. I can try messing with the image create info to get that working.

Comment: It would be interesting to try a more useful test pattern, such as a color gradient fill across the whole image in both dimensions. That would help confirm how blocks are being scrambled.

Comment: Per the Vulkan spec: "Creation of images with tiling VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR may not be supported unless other parameters meet all of the constraints: usage only includes VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT and/or VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT"

Comment: I will edit with a better test image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186208/discussion-between-solidpixel-and-slocook).

Comment: @slocook: "*I am using Vulkan with GLSL compute shaders to do post processing on a texture rendered in OpenGL.*" Um... why? If you already have OpenGL working, why not use OpenGL's compute shaders to do that post-processing? The Vulkan compute shader model is no different from the OpenGL one, so you're not getting any real benefit from it.

Comment: The product actually functions like a plugin and is intended to do post processing for applications that render using either OpenGL, CUDA, or Vulkan.

Comment: @slocook Hey, how did you make the device.getMemoryFdKHR work? I can't link it since it needs to be loaded using vkGetDeviceProcAddr. How did you make it callable directly from the device as if it was loaded in vulkan.hpp? Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: @Hitokage Are you using a vk::DispatchLoaderDynamic?

Comment: @slocook Hmm never heard of it. Thanks, I will look it up!